# Keeping a cardholder hanging from a lanyard always facing the same side

Tags: applied-mechanics, dynamics

I always have the problem of having my ID cardholder flipping when I'm walking, and people not being able to see the side with the information.

I cannot double-print this ID front and back so I wonder: how can I retrofit the cardholder or lanyard so it always faces the same way? I have thought of adding asymmetrical weight or stiffening part of the lanyard, but I do not have much physics or simulation knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

If the cardholder can be attached to the lanyard at both corners rather than at one point in the middle then it will tend to straighten out.

Alternatively a piece of self-adhesive Velcro (hook side) attached to the rear of the cardholder might give enough grip on clothing to keep it in place. This may cause "pilling" of your clothes though.

Another option is to stick a flat magnet to the back of the cardholder and wear another inside your clothing to hold it in place.